# CodeIgniter parameterize integer and string

Tags: codeigniter

```
$code = Array(1,2,3,4)
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 IN (?)";
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($code));
```

`$this->db->last_query()` will show

```
"SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 IN ('1,2,3,4')"
```

How can I remove the single quote in the IN condition?

Even if the `$code` is array of strings, example

```
$code = Array('This one', 'Next code', 'And this')
```

the statement will be:

```
"SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 IN ('This one, Next Code, And This')"
```

Am I missing something ?

TIA.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this simple and alternate way

```
$this->db->where_in('Field1',$code);
$this->db->get('Table1');
```

Answer (score 1):

From codeigniter active record [manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

> $this->db->where() accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it
>   to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table
>   names with backticks.

```
$this->db->where('MATCH (field) AGAINST ("value")', NULL, FALSE);
```

So, put a 3rd parameter on a where clause with FALSE

Then your query should be

```
 $this->db->select('*')
          ->where('Field1 IN('.$code.'),NULL,FALSE)
          ->get('Table1');
```